# Applying a custom identifier on variables within a class

Tags: c#

As part of a random data generator, I have a class which contains various string parameters, such as:

```
class Container
{
    string FirstName {get; set;}
    string LastName {get; set;}
    string ContactNo {get; set;}
}
```

Note that I require ContactNo as a string to retain the leading 0.

I then loop through these parameters and generate a random  value programmatically, however I need to be able to determine when to generate a random word (for FirstName & LastName) or number (for ContactNumber).

```
BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Public |
    BindingFlags.NonPublic |
    BindingFlags.Instance |
    BindingFlags.Static;

foreach (FieldInfo field in typeof(Container).GetFields(flags))
{
    // Check custom identifier to see whether a random word or number is required.
}
```

I *could* include some  kind of identifier in the variable names which suggest whether numbers or words are required, however I perform a similar task to apply headers to an output csv and use the variable names for this, but I don't really want to have the headers containing this information. I guess could always go with this approach but remove the identifier, but that seems a bit messy.

Can anyone point out another way I can achieve this?

### EDIT

Thanks to ChrisDunaway for highlighting that you need to look over the Properties instead of the Fields, such as:

```
BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Public |
    BindingFlags.NonPublic |
    BindingFlags.Instance |
    BindingFlags.Static;

foreach (Propertyinfo field in typeof(Container).GetProperties(flags))
{
    // Check custom identifier to see whether a random word or number is required.
}
```

Comment: You could create an attribute and decorate each property. The attribute would allow you to indicate what kind of random string to generate.

Comment: Make a struct with an enum and a string. Change your Container class to use that struct

Comment: You could use Public for the parameters that everybody uses and Private for the ones that contains information.

Comment: Attributes power, ftw :)

Comment: Just as an aside, `GetFields` won't return those properties (since they're properties!).  You need `GetProperties` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions guys. Adding attributes to the variable/property sounds like the way forward, but couldn't figure out what to use as an identifier. Are you able to provide an example?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway, what your saying makes sense, however this code seems to work(?)

Comment: @ChrisDunaway, apologies for doubting you, you were right. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use attributes. This may help you:

```
class Container
{
    string FirstName { get; set; }
    string LastName { get; set; }
    [IsNumber]
    string ContactNo { get; set; }
}

public class IsNumber : Attribute { }

public static void test()
    {
        var flags = BindingFlags.Public |
                   BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                   BindingFlags.Instance |
                   BindingFlags.Static;

        foreach (PropertyInfo property in typeof(Container).GetProperties(flags))
        {
            if (property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(IsNumber), true).Length > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("property " + property.Name + " is number");
                // this is a number field
            }
            // Check custom identifier to see whether a random word or number is required.
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is perfect, gives me exactly what I need to identify what data is required. Thanks for the example!

Comment: @mrmb, I spoke to soon, in this example the if statement never evaluates to true. Any ideas why?

Comment: @Klicker, You are right, code changed, you must loop over properties, not fields

Comment: also you can use fields instead, namely 'string FirstName; ' not 'string FirstName { get; set; }'